# Finding root via solveset

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I need to evaluate the maxima of a function via solveset (or some alternative tool).

Currently my code is:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit as cf
from sympy import symbols, Interval, S, Float, Rational
from sympy.logic.boolalg import Or
from sympy import solveset

x = symbols('x', real=True)

"""
Fitting raw data via:
    1. np.genfromtxt(...)
    2. fitParams, fitCovariances = cf(fitFunc, x_values, y_values)
gives the foolowing parameters:
"""

p1 = -0.351519665611521
p2 = -0.025153022792473
p3 = 0.005404053033914
p4 = -0.000875763032580
p5 = 0.000070700828439
p6 = -0.000002224914318
p7 = 0.871513745522901

fitParams = np.array([p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7])

def function(x, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7):
        return p7*x**(S(2)/3) + p6*x**6 + p5*x**5 + p4*x**4 + p3*x**3 + p2*x**2 + p1*x
```

where the parameters 'p*' come from the previous fitting of raw data.

I need to extract the maxima of:

```
energy = function(x, *fitParams) + var1*x
```

as function of the variable 'var1'.

So I'm trying to get the roots of its derivative:

```
energy_dx = energy.diff(x)
```

via "solveset":

```
solutions = solveset(energy_dx, x, domain=S.Reals)
```

It happens that for some values of "var1" solveset is able to evaluate the solution but not for other values.
In these latter cases the code gives:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/polys/polytools.py", line 3544, in nroots
    cleanup=cleanup, error=False, extraprec=f.degree()*10)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mpmath/calculus/polynomials.py", line 196, in polyroots
    % maxsteps)
mpmath.libmp.libhyper.NoConvergence: Didn't converge in maxsteps=50 steps.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./myscript.py", line 146, in <module>
    solutions = solveset(energy_dx, x, S.Reals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/solvers/solveset.py", line 921, in solveset
    return _solveset(f, symbol, domain, _check=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/solvers/solveset.py", line 734, in _solveset
    solver)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/solvers/solveset.py", line 535, in _solve_radical
    f_y_sols = solveset_solver(eq, y)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/solvers/solveset.py", line 674, in <lambda>
    solver = lambda f, x, domain=domain: _solveset(f, x, domain)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/solvers/solveset.py", line 738, in _solveset
    result += _solve_as_rational(equation, symbol, domain)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/solvers/solveset.py", line 385, in _solve_as_rational
    return _solve_as_poly(g, symbol, domain)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/solvers/solveset.py", line 430, in _solve_as_poly
    quintics=True, domain='EX')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/polys/polyroots.py", line 989, in roots
    for r in f.nroots():
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/polys/polytools.py", line 3553, in nroots
    n, maxsteps))
mpmath.libmp.libhyper.NoConvergence: convergence to root failed; try n < 15 or maxsteps > 50
```

Here I'm not able to figure out how to modify the 'n' or 'maxsteps' values.

I'm newbye in coding via Python, so I'd really appreciate any of your suggestions.
Python is in the 3.6.5 version and all modules are up to date.

---

June 02: currently I'm not able to reproduce the problem

Comment: Can you include some actual values for `p*`? If you obtain them from curve fitting then they are some numerical values. Is it sufficient to get the numerical value of `x` at which the fitted curve becomes maximum and the numerical value of the curve? By using `solveset` you are hoping to get an analytical expression even though `p*` are not analytical?